# Serial sniffer?

Tags: serial, communication

I have a serial RS-232 connection from a PC's com1: port to a vendor's device. The vendor's device is going to 100% CPU utilization and the vendor claims that our software on our PC is causing that.

When we unplug the cable, the utilization drops to less than 20%.  I can't see in our application how that could be happening.  I'd like to "sniff" the traffic between the PC and the vendor's device by placing a Raspberry Pi between the 2 and displaying that traffic.

I've got 2 serial to USB cables, and the needed gender changers, and I'm trying the `socat` and `screen` packages, with various combinations of parameters, but I can't get it to work.  I also have some null modems, but am not sure whether they're needed (I've tried them with various programs/paramters, but I can't get it).

I have used the serial/USB cables sucessfully on the RPi, so I know that works.  I am setting the baud rates using stty, but am not sure how to set the data/stop/parity settings.  I've tried things suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811013/socat-two-serial-port-together), [here](http://technostuff.blogspot.com/2008/10/some-useful-socat-commands.html) and other places.  With `screen` I can sometimes see line noise characters, and when I specify the `-d -d -d -d` option on socat, I get msgs that the ports are opened, and lines are generated when I run the app on the PC. But the app isn't working because the RPi isn't transparent - the communication's being corrupted.  I've tried setting `raw` and other various params.

Anyone got the correct incantation?

Comment: Use the TX and later the RX line physically to read the traffic on an other device.